# Magento 2 category structure is displayed wrong

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category-tree

For some reason my category structure on the frontend and admin panel show different results. Check image below:

On the frontend my category "DATORER" have 4 subcategories but in the admin panel I only have 2 active subcategories.

I'm importing the products and category structure from a system called IcePim and
one thing to be noted is that the frontend are displaying the correct category structure I've set up in IcePim while it's being displayed wrong from the Admin panel.

Is there something I have missed to why they show different results?

I have run tried

- rm -rf var/di var/generation
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- optimze database

Frontend
[image]

Admin panel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a matter of value scoping. What I think happens is that during your data import, the values are set on the store view level, but when you enter the admin you don't see that directly from the start as you are initially browsing the **Scope: All Store Views** which is the default store (different than the store view that holds your data).

If you **change the scope to be the store view** (from the upper left corner of your category admin page), you should now see your category as enabled.

Please check and let me know if you need more details.

---

***LE:*** we need to identify the values stored in your db:

let's retrieve the values stored on the category for the status attribute (replace `<category_id`> with the ID of your category of interest):

**COMMERCE**

```sql
select * from catalog_category_entity_int where row_id in (select row_id from catalog_category_entity where entity_id = <category_id>) and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='is_active' and entity_type_id='3');
```

**OPEN SOURCE**

```sql
select * from catalog_category_entity_int where entity_id = <category_id> and attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='is_active' and entity_type_id='3');
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I changed the Store View in the upper left corner to the specific Store View that's being displayed on the frontend but it's stil the same problem.

Comment: ok, now that's weird... normally, on a default menu only active / enabled categories should appear. so my next question is - are you using magento default menu OR a 3rd party extension OR a CMS block rendered as a menu where categories are added manually?

Comment: Yeah I would agree on that... The category structure is being imported from IcePim's own custom extensions that they have added to my website.

Comment: It's the default menu block :)

Comment: please check the edit on my answer and run the query (depending on your Magento edition) and see if you can catch the idea on what store the values are stored.

Comment: Hi! I my result is  `value_id = 2, attribute_id = 46, store_id = 0, entity_id = 2, value = 1`

Comment: can you please confirm that your category ID = 2? normally, this is the root category and it is not displayed on the menu.

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry about that, check my updated answer in the top.

Comment: very weird - your category appears as enabled on all stores and you see it as disabled on the admin side :( i believe i am running out of ideas, unfortunately :(

Comment: Not to worry, thanks for the help :)